# Flutter RevenueCat SDK not working on web

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

For my flutter IOS/Android app i use https://pub.dev/packages/purchases_flutter ( RevenueCat ) to manage subscription and it's working perfectly well.

Now i want to export my flutter into a webapp using : Flutter build web
I got that error :
**''No implementation found for method setupPurchases on channel purchases_flutter''**

That's because purchases_flutter is not made for webapp for now.

**My question:**
I really need to export my application into a webapp, is there a way i can avoid that kind of error? Can i trick my code to skip every part that refer to that package?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can put a condition before initializing revenuecat plugin so if you are on the web it skip that part and the application can build correctly

To check if you are on web

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```